# Java Networking - Starting multiple Server Sockets on different ports parallely in the ame Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, network-programming, serversocket

I need to start multiple ports on the Server parallely and all the server sockets should block on socket.accept().

The same Thread needs to then start the client sockets (many) to connect to particular ServerSocket(s).

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Why are you pratting about with 'same thread' thingy?  Make one server class, no matter how as long as they can execute on their own, then make three instances of it.  Same with clients.

Answer (score 1):

No - you cannot "start multiple ports" - because ports can be used/binded, but not started.

"server sockets should block on socket.accept()" - sockets cannot block, only threads can.

"The same Thread needs to then start the client sockets" - sockets are open and closed, not started.